# typeError: cannot read properties of undefined Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, testing

```
DisplayComponent
should handle outputs
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vote')
it('should handle outputs', () => { component.voterTestComponent.vote(true);
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(getElementById("#lastVote").textContent).toEqual("Yes");
});
```

[image: 1]

I tried to change the method name but did not worked

Comment: I think the '#' in front of 'lastVote' needs to be removed.

Comment: by the website roles, I should not changes the testing part (2), therefor My code has some  thing incorrect

Comment: Yes, there is probably an error on your end as well, as Krenom stated correctly in his answer. But I can see on your screenshot that the css-selector reads `lastVote` and not `#lastVote`. I think the `#` was a typo by the person who wrote this test, so you should inform them to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are two parts:

One is the undefined error, the other is your get element.

For the first, I believe kellermat's comment is probably right: Your `getElementById('#lastVote')` shouldn't have the `#` in it.

It's not a css selector - at which point you would be right to use a `#`. It's already expecting an id, so it doesn't need or want the `#` to identify it as being such.

Just `getElementById('lastVote')` should do it.

Secondly, the actual error which is above that line anyway - the error says it all: `component.voterTestComponent` is undefined.

Given the error is not `(reading 'voterTestComponent')`, it means that `component` is filled, but there is no value to the `voterTestComponent` on that `component` object.

Presumably your other tests (that we get a peek at) are passing? They are making use of, e.g., `component.voterTestComponent.yesAnswer` and so must be properly populated.

What is different between those tests and this one such that it wouldn't be properly populated?